# Convert FILETIME to string, or else

Tags: c++

I want to store the filename and the creation time of every file present in a directory. I found the following code which browses a directory and detects every file. The problem is that I don't know how to store the values from WIN32_FIND_DATA. cFilename shouldn't be too hard, it's TCHAR (but I'm beginner in C++), and ftCreationTime is a structure so it can't be stored into a vector because it has no constructor.

The final goal of this piece of code is to detect if a new file with the same has been created in the directory. Some pictures are regularly created and deleted by a software, and regarding if the file is new or not it sends an alert to a pager. So I have to find a way to check if the file is new or not, otherwise the pager will always ring :p

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> pictures;

HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;

hFind = FindFirstFile(TEXT("C:\\temp\\*"), &ffd);
do
{
    Sleep(1000);
    bool isDirectory = ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
    if(isDirectory)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"),ffd.cFileName);

    }
    else
    {
        //here is where I want to store the cFilename and ftCreationTime in the map
        //something strange here
        //tprintf returns the good filename but cout returns a character string like 0019FB2C for every file found
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"),ffd.cFileName );
        std::cout << "FileTime: " << ffd.cFileName << std::endl;
    }
}while(FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
FindClose(hFind);
```

Comment: "ftCreationTime is a structure so it can't be stored into a vector because it has no constructor." - of course a structure has a constructor, if you don't define one, the compiler will *always* generate the default constructor.

Comment: If you have a unicode build, then you should use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`. You can use macros to define the appropriate one as `tcout`.

Comment: thokra : thank for the correction, I had read basics in c++ so I made this mistake
jliv902 : a big thank you for your code, I'm gonna try it ;)

Comment: "Convert FILETIME to string, or else" Or else what? You'll eat our baby… carrots if we don't want them?

Comment: Thanks for this pertinent comment, especially when the question has been resolved a long time ago ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could do for this.
I used a vector, but you can adjust this to your needs.
Please note that this hasn't been tested or debugged.
I also did this all in one .cpp file; you should probably break this up.

First, create a Picture struct:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef std::basic_string <TCHAR> tstring ;
typedef std::basic_ostream <TCHAR> tstream ;

#ifdef _UNICODE
#define tcout std::wcout
#else
#define tcout std::cout
#endif

struct Picture
{
    Picture (const tstring &name, const FILETIME &ft) ;

    tstring name ;
    FILETIME creation_time ;

    friend bool operator== (const Picture &lhs, const Picture &rhs) ;
    friend bool operator!= (const Picture &lhs, const Picture &rhs) ;
    friend tstream& operator<< (tstream& ts, const Picture &pic) ;
};

Picture::Picture (const tstring &name, const FILETIME &ft) : name (name), creation_time (ft)
{
}

bool operator== (const Picture &lhs, const Picture &rhs)
{
    return ((lhs.name == rhs.name) && (::CompareFileTime (&lhs.creation_time, &rhs.creation_time) == 0)) ;
}

bool operator!= (const Picture &lhs, const Picture &rhs)
{
    return !(operator== (lhs, rhs)) ;
}

tstream& operator<< (tstream& ts, const Picture &pic)
{
    ts  << pic.name << _T (", FileTime (HI, LO): (") 
        << pic.creation_time.dwHighDateTime << _T (", ")
        << pic.creation_time.dwLowDateTime << _T (")") ;
    return ts ;
}
```

Then implement a function that prints out new files.

```
void PrintNewPictures (std::vector <Picture> &vecPicsOld, const tstring &dir)
{
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd ;

    std::vector <Picture> vecPics ;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(dir.data (), &ffd) ;
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Return an error or throw an exception
        return ;
    }

    do {
        Picture pic (ffd.cFileName, ffd.ftCreationTime) ;
        if (std::find (vecPicsOld.begin (), vecPicsOld.end (), pic) == vecPicsOld.end ()) {
            // Print that this is a new Picture.
            tcout << pic << std::endl ;
        }

        vecPics.push_back (pic) ;

    } while (::FindNextFile (hFind, &ffd) != NULL) ;
    ::FindClose (hFind) ;

    // This keeps the vector fresh so it won't build up old values.
    std::swap (vecPics, vecPicsOld) ;
}
```

Here's and example of how you would use this:

```
int main (void) 
{
    std::vector <Picture> vecPics ;
    while (1) {
        ::Sleep (1000) ;
        PrintNewPictures (vecPics, _T ("C:\\temp\\*")) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: A big thank. I couldn't test because of this :    Picture::Picture (const tstring &name, const FILETIME &ft) : name (name), creation_time (ft)      Visual Studio doesnt understand the ":" (this is in .cpp). And when I try to declare it in .h, exactly like this, it tells me it expects a "{" (so to be a good constructor)

Comment: And I just love the way you find out the new pictures : if (std::find (vecPicsOld.begin (), vecPicsOld.end (), pic) == vecPicsOld.end ()). So elegant dude !

Comment: I wrote this in Visual Studio 2012, but it should work on Visual Studio 2008 as well. That `:` is the beginning of a [constructor initialization list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/). Notice the brackets that come after it. Make sure you didn't leave off a semicolon at the end of any struct or class.

Comment: I'm with 2010. I had seen your semicolons and tried to add them to the function in the header. Well if it doesn't work I'm gonna try to declare the Picture otherly in the function. Thanks a lot for your jliv ;)